# How can I inject a Typoscript object into "wrap"?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using `gridelements` as an extension, but I'm sure this doesn't matter regarding my question.

I have an element like:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    1 {
        columns {
            10 < .default
            10.wrap = <div class="class1">|</div>
        }   
        wrap = <div class="class3"><div class="class2">|</div></div>
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to insert a menu, which will exist as a Typoscript object at this place:

```
wrap = <div class="class3"><div class="class2">[>>MENU<<]|</div></div>
```

I tried this:

```
wrap.cObject = COA
wrap.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <div class="class3"><div class="class2">
    20 < temp.menu
    30 = TEXT
    30.value = </div></div>
}
```

Which works as it shows the menu, but it also fails, as it destroys the wrap itself.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it using `prepend`, `append` and a blank `wrap`:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    1 {
        columns {
            10 < .default
            10.wrap = <div class="class1">|</div>
        }   
        wrap = |

        prepend = COA
        prepend {
            10 = TEXT
            10.value = <div class="class3"><div class="class2">
            20 < temp.menu
        }

        append = COA
        append {
            10 = TEXT
            10.value = </div></div>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Michael True that - there was a timer of 2 to 4 days until you can accept your own answer. So I simply forgot.

Comment: Why was that downvoted? If someone's got a better solution, please share.